# Forward engineering mysql Foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, reverse-engineering

im trying to forward engineer my EER diagram in mysql workbench but i seem to be not able to do it
ive got a couple one to many relationships and also changed the names of the foreign keys but to no avail :(
this is from the error log

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'lagerprogram.werkzeugsätze_gierth' (errno: 150)
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugsätze_gierth`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugsätze_gierth` (
      `werkzeugführung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `messerhalter` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `zentrierkronen` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `spanvorichtung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `werkzeugsatzQ` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`werkzeugführung`, `messerhalter`, `zentrierkronen`, `spanvorichtung`),
      INDEX `fk_werkzeugsätze_gierth_maschinen_idx` (`werkzeugsatzQ` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_werkzeugsätze_gierth_maschinen`
        FOREIGN KEY (`werkzeugsatzQ`)
        REFERENCES `lagerprogram`.`maschinen` (`werkzeugsatz`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

And this is my create statement

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `lagerprogram` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lagerprogram`.`maschinen`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram`.`maschinen` (
  `typ` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `werkzeugsatz` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `maschinenkörper` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `elektrik` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pneumatic` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `hydraulik` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `kühlvorrichtung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `vorschubeinheit` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`typ`, `werkzeugsatz`, `maschinenkörper`, `elektrik`, `pneumatic`, `hydraulik`, `kühlvorrichtung`, `vorschubeinheit`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugsätze_gierth`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugsätze_gierth` (
  `werkzeugführung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `messerhalter` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `zentrierkronen` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `spanvorichtung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `werkzeugsatzQ` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`werkzeugführung`, `messerhalter`, `zentrierkronen`, `spanvorichtung`),
  INDEX `fk_werkzeugsätze_gierth_maschinen_idx` (`werkzeugsatzQ` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_werkzeugsätze_gierth_maschinen`
    FOREIGN KEY (`werkzeugsatzQ`)
    REFERENCES `lagerprogram`.`maschinen` (`werkzeugsatz`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugführungen`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugführungen` (
  `länge` INT NULL,
  `wf_komplett` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `jahresbedarf` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `flansch` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `oberteilführung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `flansch_mit_führung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `passfeder` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `typQ` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flansch`, `oberteilführung`, `flansch_mit_führung`, `passfeder`),
  INDEX `fk_werkzeugführungen_werkzeugsätze_gierth1_idx` (`typQ` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_werkzeugführungen_werkzeugsätze_gierth1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`typQ`)
    REFERENCES `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugsätze_gierth` (`werkzeugführung`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lagerprogram`.`flansch`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram`.`flansch` (
  `bestellt` INT NOT NULL,
  `fertigung` INT NULL,
  `lieferant` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `lager` INT NULL,
  `lagerplatz` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `gewicht` DECIMAL NULL,
  `e_k_preis` DECIMAL NULL,
  `v_k_preis` DECIMAL NULL,
  `flanschQ` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bestellt`),
  INDEX `fk_flansch_werkzeugführungen1_idx` (`flanschQ` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_flansch_werkzeugführungen1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`flanschQ`)
    REFERENCES `lagerprogram`.`werkzeugführungen` (`flansch`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Have you created the `maschinen` table first?

Comment: @Barmar yes, i posted the create statement aswell now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column referenced in a foreign key needs to have an index on it. So you need to change the definition of the `maschinen` table to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lagerprogram`.`maschinen` (
  `typ` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `werkzeugsatz` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `maschinenkörper` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `elektrik` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pneumatic` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `hydraulik` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `kühlvorrichtung` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `vorschubeinheit` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`typ`, `werkzeugsatz`, `maschinenkörper`, `elektrik`, `pneumatic`, `hydraulik`, `kühlvorrichtung`, `vorschubeinheit`),
  KEY (`werkzeugsatz`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Or you can change the order of the columns in the `PRIMARY KEY` so that `werkzeugsatz` is first:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`werkzeugsatz`, `typ`, `maschinenkörper`, `elektrik`, `pneumatic`, `hydraulik`, `kühlvorrichtung`, `vorschubeinheit`)
```

Comment: it worked like a charm !
But i didnt understand it ? :(
is it because it references wekzeugsatz and thats why it has to be created first ?

Comment: Only the first column in a composite key gets an index of its own, the rest are nested.